# Access application deployed in cloud foundry publicly

Tags: deployment, war, cloud-foundry

I have deployed a war application using cf push APP-NAME in our company cloud foundry hosting and application is available on APP-NAME.DOMAIN-NAME. Currently application is accessible only after connecting to VPN. I want to make application available on public domain. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to talk to your company's platform operations team and likely your company's networking team as well.

To make an app publicly accessible, you need to have a publicly resolvable domain and traffic from the public internet needs to be routed to your company's Cloud Foundry platform. Beyond that, you also need your company's platform operations team to add the public domain to Cloud Foundry, so it's an option for you to map routes to your application using that public domain.

If you get your company to set that up, then the good news is that you don't have to do anything different as an application developer. Once you map a route using the public domain to your app, traffic will be able to reach your app.